# How To: Excel VBA Command Button Enters UserForm Values to Current Row?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a UserForm "UserForm1" that takes values (Lesson, Instructor, Start Time, etc.) from ComboBoxes and saves them to a designated sheet "InstructorHours".  The CommandButton "Save" saves the selected values in the next available line on the "InstructorHours" sheet.  What I'm having trouble with is having the CommandButton save the same information into a currently selected row on another Worksheet "Calendar".  Ideally I would like to click within a row on my "Calendar" sheet and input the values from the User from into the row I've selected.

```css
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    'next available row
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("InstructorHours")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.ComboBox5.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.ComboBox6.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        End With
    'Clear input controls.
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox3.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox4.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox5.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox6.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: But you are defining `Set ws = Worksheets("InstructorHours")`. You mentioned it had to be `Calendar`

Comment: Then you can just do `lrow = Selection.Row`

Comment: What trouble are you having and what possible things have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Where you define the .cells, you might try .selection for the first, then you can offset the row (1 to 6) from selection for each subsequent entry (accounts for entry 2 to 7).

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to work on something active, you would want something "Active" (e.g. ActiveSheet or ActiveCell) for your active-selection activities.

I would recommend another Command Button for the following (Writing this up off the top of my head, haven't verified the code):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Input based on the selection
    ActiveCell.Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(2,0).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(3,0).Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(4,0).Value = Me.ComboBox5.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(5,0).Value = Me.ComboBox6.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(6,0).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value

'Clear input controls.
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox3.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox4.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox5.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox6.Value = ""

End Sub
```

That should provide, at least, a starting point.